# Sonarqube: Test coverage comes as 0

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, coverlet

I am using sonar integration for the c# x unit test project. But always test coverage is coming as 0. How can I resolve this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

coverlet is the nuget responsible for sonar integration to x unit test projects. Adding **coverlet.msbuild** and **coverlet.collector** nuget resolve the issue.